# GUI Firefox, Safari and other apps freeze after 10.11.3 update

Tags: performance, ui

Some apps seem to freeze when they were started at login. The apps are still responsive, but the GUI does not update. Did anyone else experience this problem? What can be done to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with the standard 'troubleshooting toolkit'..

- Fix permissions, Verify & if necessary Repair disk, using Disk Utility.
- Reset Home folder permissions & ACLs using [OnyX](http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html)  - Maintenance tab/permissions, tick the box at the top then Execute. (Make sure you get the right version for your OS.)
- Reset the [SMC](https://support.apple.com/HT201295) (instructions depend on Mac model)
- Reset the [NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/HT204063)

  1. At the boot chimes, hold  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>P</kbd>   <kbd>R</kbd>
  2. Keep holding all 4 keys until you hear the chimes again, then release
- Start in [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/HT201262)

  1. Start or restart your Mac.
  2. Immediately after you hear the startup sound, press and hold the Shift key.
  3. Release the Shift key when you see the Apple logo appear on the screen.
  4. Leave a few minutes after login for caches to rebuild, then reboot normally.
- Update to 10.9.5 using the [10.9.5 combo update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1760?), not the delta from App Store